# How do you make the pen line thicker in Photoshop CC (2014)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Trying to make the pen line thicker in Photoshop CC 2014. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Do you mean stroke or the empty pen line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PEN tool itself is only depicted as a hairline. Once you've completed the path, then you need to fill it or apply a "stroke" to it using the BRUSH or the PENCIL or some other tool.

To do this, you complete your path, then right-click on the path and you'll be given a list of possible options (including Make a Selection..., Fill Path..., and Stroke Path...) - Select "Stroke Path...".

You now have options of what TOOL will be used to render the path. Whatever tool you select will use the most recent settings of that tool. So you'll have to plan ahead. For example, if you have been using the brush with a soft edge at 10 pixels diameter, the path will be stroked with that brush and at the current size that you were last using.

I hope this was helpful.

Chris