# Photoshop Pen Tool - path lines are too thick

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

In recent versions of Photoshop, when I use the Pen Tool, the lines it lays down are like big fat rubbery noodles that obscure the image beneath.

<sub>Here's an image for comparison of the older (left) and newer (right) Pen Tool lines:</sub>

[image: Photoshop Pen Tool line thickness comparison]

I didn't see an option to change it in Photoshop's Preferences, and searching online I have only found explanations for how to use the Pen Tool to make strokes of various thickness *on the artwork*. I mean in the interface, they're too thick for me and interfering with my productivity. Is there a way to revert to hairline thickness like in older versions of Photoshop?

I want the exact opposite of [what this person was asking for](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77752/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After selecting the Pen Tool, at the top bar menu there's a settings icon

[image]

> This opens the Path Options dialog box where you can change the thickness of the path outline from as small as 0.5 pixels to as large as 3 pixels. You can also choose a different color for the path. I'll set the Thickness to 3 px and the Color to Magenta. Note that these settings are there only to help you see your path as you're working. They have no effect on the actual appearance of the path in the document. To close the Path Options dialog box, click again on the gear icon:

[image]

[*Source*](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/use-curvature-pen-tool-photoshop-cc-2018/)

Comment: Ah, got it! I definitely changed that by mistake while using **the line tool** and trying to adjust the thickness of *the lines I was drawing*. I was under the impression that items in the Options Bar were only for changing the output of the tools, not their appearance in the interface. Since that setting is shared between path-based tools it affected my Pen Tool as well. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: No! Doesn't work for version 22.3.0 I follow above instructions and get no line whatsoever for pen path... just dots... nothing visible.

Answer (score 1):

I am using latest version 20.0.0 and getting the same output as your older version was getting.

I guess its simple, you just need to set correct value of your **stroke**, just select pen tool & you will get stroke option in top-bar.

[image: Pen-tool stroke]

Hope it works for you!